# Net Core: TagBuilder Edit an Existing Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0, tag-helpers

I want to edit/modify the CSS class for an existing TagBuilder.

Currently the Tag is:

```
div.Attributes.Add("class", "checkbox");
```

I want to change it to below, after the previous statement already executed.

```
div.Attributes.Add("class", "book");
```

How would I conduct this?
Currently I have to Delete/Remove Attribute, and Readd. Just curious if there is more efficient way.

```
checkbox.Attributes.Remove("class");
checkbox.MergeAttribute("class", "book");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `MergeAttribute` overload accepting a boolean to overwrite the existing value.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.mergeattribute?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#System_Web_Mvc_TagBuilder_MergeAttribute_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)

> Adds a new attribute or optionally replaces an existing attribute in
>   the opening tag.

```cs
TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");

div.Attributes.Add("class", "checkbox");
// <div class="checkbox"></div>

div.MergeAttribute("class", "book", true);
// <div class="book"></div>
```

Comment: i dont want to append, I want to delete and reinsert something else